# Javascript Storing Multiple Data Objects In An Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am not a pro with javascript or arrays so there is a good chance I am not asking the right question or using the correct terminology.  Anyways here is what I am trying to do.

Using PHP I am able to grab data from googles places API.  Once I have all the data from my PHP code I want to put that data into a javascript array.  Lets say I get 5 places from googles API I would want 5 entries in the array and each entry with name, address, lat, lng.

I tried to use this code for creating the array but it doesn't create 5 entries in the array, it creates 1 entry in the array for each data object.

```
var data = []; 
            data.push({name:"BotanaCare"}, {lat:"39.904374"}, {lng:"-104.990527"}, {address:"11450 Cherokee Street A7, Northglenn"});
            data.push({name:"The Green Solution"}, {lat:"39.901838"}, {lng:"-104.979542"}, {address:"Malley Heights, 470 Malley Drive, Northglenn"});
            data.push({name:"Doc's Apothecary"}, {lat:"39.897978"}, {lng:"-104.963226"}, {address:"2100 East 112th Avenue, Northglenn"});
            data.push({name:"Emerald City"}, {lat:"39.789952"}, {lng:"-105.025937"}, {address:"5115 Federal Boulevard, Denver"});
            data.push({name:"La Conte's Clone Bar and Dispensary"}, {lat:"39.790864"}, {lng:"-104.977946"}, {address:"5194 Washington Street, Denver"});
```

Once I have the data in the proper javascript array I will be running some more code to randomly pick a "google place" from that array but for each randomly picked "place" i need the address, lat, long, and name.

Hopefully some one can point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data.push({name:"BotanaCare"}, {lat:"39.904374"}, {lng:"-104.990527"}, {address:"11450 Cherokee Street A7, Northglenn"});
```

creates and adds four objects to the array. Every argument you pass to `.push` is added as individual element to the array. It's equivalent to

```
data.push({name:"BotanaCare"}); // object with only property name
data.push({lat:"39.904374"});   // object with only property lat
// ...
```

If you only want to push a single object, then you have to create a single object (I changed the formatting to make it more readable):

```
data.push({ // object with properties name, lat, lng and address
    name:"BotanaCare",
    lat:"39.904374",
    lng:"-104.990527",
    address:"11450 Cherokee Street A7, Northglenn"
});
```

Have a look at the [MDN documentation to learn more about objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).